# Mostrar todas las categorías que tiene una taxonomía personalizada

Tags: php, wordpress

Necesito mostrar una lista con todas las categorías que tiene la taxonomía que cree, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

De esta manera cree la taxonomía:

```
function crear_taxonomia_directorioEmprede() {
 $etiquetas = array(
'name' => __( 'categoria emprede' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Categoria de directorios' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Buscar directorios' ),
'all_items' => __( 'Todas los directorios' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Directorio padre' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Directorio padre:' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Editar directorios' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar directorio' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Agregar nuevo directorios' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Categorias de directorios '),
);  

 register_taxonomy(
'directorioEmprendeViveAfro',
 array('emprende'),
 array(
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'labels' => $etiquetas, 
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'directorioEmprendeViveAfro' ),
    )
  );

}
add_action( 'init', 'crear_taxonomia_directorioEmprede', 0 );
```

Encontrado varias maneras de mostrar todas las categorías pero me muestra solo  la taxonomía que viene por defecto en WordPress

Comment: Querrás decir mostrar todos los **términos**  correspondientes a la taxonomía **directorioEmprendeViveAfro**?

Comment: Asi es, eso es lo que necesito